# How to preserve the value of thread variable in a multi-threaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a code which spawns a new thread every 5 seconds and each thread periodically prints out the value of a counter. It starts up to 10 threads in total.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService task = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        // sleep 5 seconds
        sleep(5);
        task.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            int newCounter = counter.get();
            System.out.println(String.format("[%s] counter = %d" , threadName, newCounter));
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        counter.getAndIncrement();
        ++i;
    }
}

private static void sleep(int sleepTime) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
[pool-1-thread-2] counter = 1
[pool-1-thread-3] counter = 1
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 2
[pool-1-thread-2] counter = 2
[pool-1-thread-4] counter = 2
[pool-1-thread-5] counter = 2
[pool-1-thread-3] counter = 2
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-7] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-6] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-8] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-4] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-9] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-5] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-10] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 4
   .......
```

I want each thread to print out its original value, for example, pool-1-thread-1 should print out 0 or 1 (depending on whether counter gets incremented first or the thread starts first) all the time,  the second thread should emit previous counter + 1 persistently, ... such as follows:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
[pool-1-thread-2] counter = 2
[pool-1-thread-3] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
[pool-1-thread-2] counter = 2
[pool-1-thread-4] counter = 4
[pool-1-thread-5] counter = 5
[pool-1-thread-3] counter = 3
[pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
[pool-1-thread-7] counter = 7
  .......
```

My question is how do I make the newCounter local variable keeps its original value in each thread. The way I can think of is to store the mapping of thread name to its original value in a thread-safe hash table. Is there any cleaner way to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Make a class with an instance variable capturing value of AtomicInteger  and printing out the same instead of lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a value to a particular thread, you can use a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable.
The `ThreadId` sample class in the javadoc can be easily adapted to solve your use-case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService task = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    ThreadLocal<Integer> id = ThreadLocal.withInitial(counter::incrementAndGet);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        // sleep 5 seconds
        sleep(5);
        task.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println(String.format("[%s] counter = %d" , threadName, id.get()));
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        ++i;
    }
}

private static void sleep(int sleepTime) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggesiton. My use case is slightly different in two aspects: 1. The initial value of newCounter variable is passed from the main thread (the initial value is a random number) 2. The thread is running indefinitely. So if the source value changes in the main thread, the subsequent run may pick up the changed value. This is not what I want. According to http://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal, ThreadLocal should not be used in conjunction with ExecutorService. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your concerns here. Can you run the code I added and let me know why it doesn't address your requirement? The only thing different from your expected output is that `pool-1-thread-X` will not always have the counter value `X` (as you can't control the thread scheduling). But every thread will consistently keep its own value.

Comment: Here's the output:  
    [pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
    [pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
    [pool-1-thread-2] counter = 2
    [pool-1-thread-3] counter = 3
    [pool-1-thread-1] counter = 1
    [pool-1-thread-2] counter = 2
      ....
    [pool-1-thread-3] counter = 3
I also tried to bind String variable to thread with ThreadLocal construct. It works as expected. I don't care what initial value each thread picks up when it starts. I just need the threads to keep their initial value throughout their entire lifecycle. Thanks again for the help.